# Android: Save map to SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I need to save data to `SharedPreferences` in such a way where I have an object like this:

```
{
    "days": [
        {
            "exercises": [
                {
                    "name": "Bench Press",
                    "sets": 3,
                    "reps": 8
                },
                {
                    "name": "Skull Crushers",
                    "sets": 3,
                    "reps": 8
                },
                {
                    "name": "Flys",
                    "sets": 3,
                    "reps": 8
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "exercises": [
                {
                    "name": "Bench Press",
                    "sets": 3,
                    "reps": 8
                },
                {
                    "name": "Skull Crushers",
                    "sets": 3,
                    "reps": 8
                },
                {
                    "name": "Flys",
                    "sets": 3,
                    "reps": 8
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I will need to pull from the object and add to the object. I know that you can't save maps to `SharedPreferences`. I am starting to think that my best bet is to use `ObjectOutputStream` but I am not sure if that is the best bet to use internal memory. I guess I am just looking for guidance as to what my best options are.

edit: from what `Advice-Dog` said, I am thinking my best bet is to use `gson`. So does that mean that when I want to (for example) add another exercise to the second index of "days" that I will first grab the object from preferences, convert it from `gson` to an object, then add the exercise, then convert it back to `gson`, then overwrite the preferences? I am not saying this is bad I just want to know if this is what should be done and if it is advisable.

Comment: this data-structure has the problem, that one cannot differ the days - and `SharedPreferences` are rather meant to keep application settings (simple data); not to be abused as a database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When saving more complex types in Android, I would suggest using `gson`. Gson is Google's JSON parsing library, and even if you're not using JSON, you can convert your `Objects` into a JSON String, and store that easily.

For example, you can convert your list of `Objects` into a `String` like this.

```
val list : List<MyObject>  // ... add items to your list

// Convert to JSON

val string = gson.toJson(list)

// Store it into Shared Preferences
preferences.putString("list", string).apply()
```

And then you can easily get it back into a list like this.

```
// Fetch the JSON 

val string = preferences.getString("list", "")

// Convert it back into a List

val list: List<MyObject> = gson.fromJson(string, object : TypeToken<List<MyObject>>() {}.type)
```

Comment: Just a question. Does this mean that anytime I want to add a value to the object I will first convert the json to an object then add the value then convert it back to json then save over the previous preferences?

Comment: @BUInvent Yes. That may sound wasteful, but it's perfectly okay. GSON is very fast, and so is SharedPreferences. You could also keep a local copy, update it, and save it out. So you're not constantly reading it back out, but depends on your usage.

Answer (score 1):

Using JSON is the best solution but here is another solution (just to add another way to solve a problem):

you can use shared preferences keys like this:

```
for((dayIndex, day) in days.withIndex)
    for((exeIndex, exe) in day)
       for((key, value) in exe)
          addExercise(day = dayIndex, exercise = exeIndex, key = key, value = value)


fun addExercise(day: String, exercise: String, key: String, value: String) = 
     preferences.putString("day${day}_exe${exercise}_${key}", value).apply()
```

then you can get *first exercise name* from *second day* like this:

```
val first_exercise_second_day = preferences.getString("day2_exe1_name")
```

and you can add a exercise to third day like this:

```
 addExercise(day = "3", exercise = "1", key = "name", value = "Flys")
 addExercise(day = "3", exercise = "1", key = "sets", value = "5")
 addExercise(day = "3", exercise = "1", key = "reps", value = "3")
```

But to find empty day or empty exercise number you have to get all keys of shared preference and use regular expression or loops

Answer (score 1):

you can use library for google ==> Gson 
add this in dependencies in gradle

```
 implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

you can this library convert object to json as String then you can save it in shared Pref As String 
when you get it String from Pref you can convert String to object

convert json to model

```
    /*type of model*/=new Gson().fromJson(/*json string*/,/*type of model*/)
```

convert model to json as String

```
 new Gson().toJson(/*model you want to convert */)===> return String
```

must model the same hierarchy for json where make problem during converting

Model for you json must be like this model

```
  public class JSONModel implements Serializable {


    @SerializedName("days")
    private List<Day> mDays;

    public List<Day> getDays() {
        return mDays;
    }

    public void setDays(List<Day> days) {
        mDays = days;
    }

    public class Day {

        @SerializedName("exercises")
        private List<Exercise> mExercises;

        public List<Exercise> getExercises() {
            return mExercises;
        }

        public void setExercises(List<Exercise> exercises) {
            mExercises = exercises;
        }

    }
    public class Exercise {

        @SerializedName("name")
        private String mName;
        @SerializedName("reps")
        private Long mReps;
        @SerializedName("sets")
        private Long mSets;

        public String getName() {
            return mName;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            mName = name;
        }

        public Long getReps() {
            return mReps;
        }

        public void setReps(Long reps) {
            mReps = reps;
        }

        public Long getSets() {
            return mSets;
        }

        public void setSets(Long sets) {
            mSets = sets;
        }

    }

}
```